# Video processing using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, video-processing

What I need: 
- load video from client
- cut this video on chunks by timepoints
- store thuis chunks
- provide access to this video chunks for web-users

Could you please give some advices how to properly build this process using AWS infrastructure?

Comment: Do you need real time Max ?

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very broad question, so you cannot expect a very detailed answer. But lets start at least with basic puzzle pieces.

AWS may provide you infrastructure and services to support your case.

> load video from client

Commonly the uploads are to be stored in an [S3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

> cut this video on chunks by timepoints

Once the video is uploaded, you may use the [Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/) service or any application on a virtual machine (AWS EC2, AWS Batch,..) to process the uploaded video files. You can use the Elastic Transcoder to generate clips (chunks)

> - store thuis chunks - provide access to this video chunks for web-users

The chunks can be stored in S3 again and you can make a web app to [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)   (give access) to the stored chunks

This is at least basic overview, but based on your question it may be a good start